# Passing a number through intent but App force closes

Tags: java, android

I made a simple Android program that calculates two numbers and show the result in the second screen using Intent mechanism...But the problem is app is force closing when i click calculate that moves to the second screen..
I've registered the activity in the Manifest file and the app works well when handling String values..

First Screen

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int a;
int b;
int sum;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
```

Parsing the values that read in the text field to integer

```
    a = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
    sum = a+b;
```

Here i am starting an Explicit Intent with the Sum

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
    intent.putExtra("just",sum);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}); 
}

    }
```

Second Screen

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Second extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.second);
```

Here i am retrieving the sum in the intent with the key that was used in the first class

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just"));


}

    }
```

Comment: Seems you're gettting `ResourceNotFoundException` coz of this line `text.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just"))`. Always do an explicit cast to `String` when displaying a number to a `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your log cat I can't be sure it's not crashing before this, but when you set the text on this line:

```
text.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just"));
```

You're actually calling [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) method definition:

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

because you're passing it the int returned from the `getInt` call. This is looking for a resource identifier (which presumably doesn't exist, hence the crash - though again I can't be sure without your logcat output that it isn't crashing earlier).

What you need to do is get the string value of the int:

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
int sum = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just");
text.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

`setText()` is looking for a `resource id` of this value getIntent().getExtras().getInt("just"). You instead need to get the `String` value of your `int` which you are passing.

[Different setText methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

Also, you should surround your parsing in a `try/catch` or do some error checking in case a non-integer is entered

```
try
{
    a = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
    sum = a+b;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    Log.e("TAG", "You're numbers are not real numbers :\\");
}
```

Obviously you don't want to just log the exception but print an error message or something else relevant